How to elegantly preallocate a numpy array?
This is mainly framed towards Numpy arrays but I feel it's a general design problem. In many cases I have the following generic problem in scientific computing: I have to read a dataset composed of several time instances of a certain vector field, e.g. the time-varying velocity field on a number of points. Something that could be a 3D array of sizes (Npoints, 3, Ntimesteps) (3 because I have three components of a vector). I normally would have one file per timestep, so I'd have to read Ntimesteps files, but I don't know beforehand the size of each field (i.e. I don't know Npoints beforehand, but it's the same for each file). If I want to preallocate the Numpy array to store this data, I got used to doing something along these lines:
tsteps = list(glob.glob('time*.csv'))
Nsteps = len(tsteps)
with open(tsteps[0], 'r') as f:
    # do my work to get Npoints and the data of the first file
    dataset = np.zeros(Npoints, 3, Nsteps)
    dataset[:,:,0] = data_first_file
for i,f in enumerate(tsteps[1:]):
    # do my work again
    dataset[:,:,i] = data_from_tstep_i

However, this does not look very 'elegant' since I have to write twice the code to process each timestep file: once to preallocate the array and once in the loop. Is there a more elegant pattern to do this?

If this is for scientific computing, you should consider using h5 files. You can have other fields in those, such as a field with the total number of points and total number of timesteps.

Also, why did you choose the ordering (Npoints, 3, Ntimesteps) rather than (Ntimesteps, 3, Npoints)?

Also, side note, if the plan is to allocate, and then immediately fill everything from what is in the files, then you don't need to initialize to 0 (np.zeros). np.empty would do. On nowadays machine, that changes not a lot (33% gain on a very simple A=np.zeros(...); A[:]=1 vs A=np,empty(...); A[:]=1 on my machine. I have to test with A[:], because with "copy-on-write", nothing really happens before I actually use the memory). And if what you do with it is slow file I/O, then, the gain is certainly negligible. But still, it is good, I think, to be aware that 0 mean "fill with 0"

@chrslg really good point!

@jared would your combination give any performance benefits? Or is it more to fit better in a mental model?

@ffdoctor HDF5 is more performant for realistic (i.e. large) datasets. By more performant I mean the file read and write is faster and the files are smaller. See this blog for some more details and a comparison (the examples at the end where there is a large number of small datasets is unrealistic, and in your case you have 3 datasets).

i think that there's no elegant way to do it if you don't know the shape in advance. but you should initiate it inside the loop for readability
tsteps = glob.glob('time*.csv') 
for i, filename in enumerate(tsteps):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data_i = np.loadtxt(f)
        if i==0:
            dataset = np.zeros(data_i.shape[0], 3, len(tsteps))
        dataset[:,:,i] = data_i


The issue is that I don't know npoints a priori, that's why I need the first iteration outside. Maybe I should clarify it in the question, it's not simply the number of rows in the CSV file, it needs some manipulation.

you already said that in the question and i didn't pay attention. sorry. in the loop you need something like if i==0: get_Npoints, i think it's better than having this code outside the loop

python 3.11.5numpy 1.25.2
The question of elegance depends on taste and background. However, I believe it is possible to make the job at least more accurate. To achieve this, I would separate it into three steps:

Extract data from a given file
Generate a stream of data from files
Collect the data

Each step can be implemented differently, but the key idea lies in this separation. For example:
def load_from_file(file_name):
    data = None
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        # mock data
        npoints, vector_dim = 10, 3
        data = np.arange(npoints*vector_dim).reshape(npoints, vector_dim)
    return data    
    
def fetch_data(source_dir, *, pattern='time*.csv'):
    from pathlib import Path
    for source in Path(source_dir).glob(pattern):
        if source.is_file(): 
            yield load_from_file(source)
        
data = np.r_['2,3,0', *fetch_data('.', pattern='*')]    
            # 2     - stack along the axis 2
            #   3   - force each part into 3 dimensions
            #     0 - place actual dimentions at the beginning

If the logic of some steps is simple, we can combine them. For example, here's one of the good scenarios:
dtype, source, pattern = int, '.', '*.bin'
data = np.stack([np.fromfile(f, dtype).reshape(-1, 3)
                 for f in Path(source).glob(pattern)], axis=2)

If extracting data is more complicated but iterating over files is still simple, then:
def get_data(file):
    ...

data = np.stack([get_data(f) for f in Path(source).glob(pattern)
                 if f.is_file()], axis=2)

Whichever way you choose, I believe the three-step model is beneficial for getting your head around the whole process.
Note: Using numpy.stack as well as numpy.r_ in the examples above ensures that the resulting data is C_CONTIGUOUS.

P.S. In case we decide to allocate memory for the data before filling it layer by layer, we encapsulate this logic in the third step. For example:
import numpy as np

def load_from_file(file_name, *, columns=None, **np_fromfile_kwargs):
    data = None
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        data = np.fromfile(file_name, **np_fromfile_kwargs)
        match columns:
            case int(n):
                data = data.reshape(-1, n)
            case tuple(shape) | list(shape):
                data = data.reshape(shape)
    return data    
    
def fetch_data(source_dir, *, pattern='*', key=None, reverse=False,
               **loading_settings) -> (int, Iterator):
    from pathlib import Path
    files = [f for f in Path(source_dir).glob(pattern) if f.is_file()]
    files.sort(key=key, reverse=reverse)
    return len(files), (load_from_file(f, **loading_settings) for f in files)

def collect_data(source_dir, **settings):
    nlayers, data_layers = fetch_data(source_dir, **settings)
    if nlayers == 0:
        return None
    first_layer = next(data_layers)
    assert first_layer is not None
    shape = *first_layer.shape, nlayers
    dtype = first_layer.dtype
    data = np.empty(shape, dtype)
    data[..., 0] = first_layer
    for i, layer in enumerate(data_layers, 1):
        data[..., i] = layer if layer is not None else 0
    return data

Test case:
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

with TemporaryDirectory() as source_dir:
    source_dir = Path(source_dir)
    base = np.arange(10*3)
    for n in range(20):
        (base + n).tofile(source_dir/f'time{n:02}.bin')

    fetching_settings = dict(
        pattern='time*.bin', 
        key=lambda x: int(Path(x).stem.removeprefix('time')))
    loading_settings = dict(
        dtype=int, 
        columns=3)

    data = collect_data(source_dir, **(fetching_settings | loading_settings))

print(f'{data.shape = }')
print(f'{data[..., 15] = }')

# data.shape = (10, 3, 20)
# data[..., 15] = array(
#       [[15, 16, 17],
#        [18, 19, 20],
#        [21, 22, 23],
#        [24, 25, 26],
#        [27, 28, 29],
#        [30, 31, 32],
#        [33, 34, 35],
#        [36, 37, 38],
#        [39, 40, 41],
#        [42, 43, 44]])


Yes, I understand what you mean. I know that the word 'elegant' is a bit misused but I was lacking a better term. But I understand your point and it gives the idea, as @folen-gateis pointed in the comment, to separate processing from collection. Your approach is useful, but in the case of very large arrays, it can lead to costly data moving when you call r._ or stack because the arrays might not be contiguous, which defeats the point of preallocating.
